# Shell: Indirect expansion throws bad substitution I'm Windows but not Mac

Tags: bash, shell, windows-10

Here's the script I'm talking about

```
#!/bin/bash
_sv="77777777777777777a"
if [ -n "${!_sv}" ]; then
  echo "the value is there"
  ${echo} "${!sv}"
elif [ -n "${!1}" ]; then
  echo "${!1}"
else
  echo "False"
fi
```

When I run it with **sh test.sh** or as **bash test.sh**  in GNU `bash` in Windows10 (using Cmder) it give me a bad substitution error

```
dir_1/test.sh: line 2: 77777777777777777a: bad substitution
```

But the same script runs without any errors in macOS terminal shell **and in Windows10, if and only if** the variable is purely alphabetic or numeric.

**IMPORTANT**: If the _sv value is alphanumeric, it gives bad substitution error.

Please help!

Comment: 77777777777777777a is an invalid variable name, variable names can not have a digit as the first character.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is expected behavior. You get this error because your name you are trying to expand is not a valid variable name.

This check was [introduced in Bash 4.4 commit a0c0a00fc419b7](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/subst.c?id=a0c0a00fc419b7bc08202a79134fcd5bc0427071#n6664):

```
@@ -5926,6 +6661,16 @@ parameter_brace_expand_indir (name, var_is_special, quoted, quoted_dollar_atp, c
   if (t == 0)
     return (WORD_DESC *)NULL;

+  if (valid_brace_expansion_word (t, SPECIAL_VAR (t, 0)) == 0)
+    {
+      report_error (_("%s: bad substitution"), t);
+      free (t);
+      w = alloc_word_desc ();
+      w->word = &expand_param_error;
+      w->flags = 0;
+      return (w);
+    }
+
   w = parameter_brace_expand_word (t, SPECIAL_VAR(t, 0), quoted, 0, 0);
   free (t);
```

Previous versions instead expanded this to an empty string. This includes macOS's Bash 3.2.

Comment: Above is the correct explanation why the error is encountered. The way I overcame the error was by enclosing it with a if check that checks if it starts with number.